# Is there a safe version for the First<> Extension Method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to use the `First<TSource>` extension method to find the first occurence of a specific object in a `List<>` I have, but it might not be in the list, and I don't want it throwing me an exception because I don't believe it's good practice having an empty catch scope, so I just want it to return null instead.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

Comment: If my condition isn't found in the list, won't this give me the first element of the list by default ??

Comment: Nope, it will return the default value of TSource, which is null for a reference type.

Comment: Thanks then! I was sure it returns the first value of the list, don't even know why... :)